# How can I manually add text onto a map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, text

Is there a way to put river, towns etc names beside labeling in QGIS?
Can you manually type text, determine size, and place it where and as you wish on the map?

Comment: You could try using annotations, started at qgis 2.0. That is except from labeling within qgis, or manually labelling within the map composer. I havn't really tried it, but here is a link to youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pDBuSbQ02o

Comment: Annotations are good but can i rotate them? Another problem is when i place them and then zoom out they dont stay in one place but move with zoom. Same problem i had with Labeling. Can i add annotations inside print Composer?

Comment: Within print composer you can use the labeling option (add new label function). It is a floating text window in which you can manually edit text, fonts and location. Though it seems to be an inefficient way to work - I guess that is wat you were looking for. I havn't really tried annotations yet - so can't help you with it at the moment.

Comment: Never mind i find solution - adding line vector then labeling it and then make it transparent, that way i can have text around like mountain name or region name. Thanks for help.